# Flutter/Dart variables lost / keep getting reinitialized when trying to get from different class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

The variables keep getting reinitialized when accessed from another class.

I have a class, in its separate dart source file, declared as such:

**helper_provider.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BuilderHelperProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  var _builderDetails;

  void setBuilderDetails(inputDetails) {
    this._builderDetails = inputDetails;
  }

  get builderDetails {
    return _builderDetails;
  }
}
```

and I initialize the variable in main.dart

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:builder_project/helpers/helper_provider.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => BuilderHelperProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('builders')
                  .doc('builder id')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, builderSnap) {
                if (builderSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                final _builderDetails = builderSnap.data;

                BuilderHelperProvider().setBuilderDetails(_builderDetails);

                print('builder Details: ${BuilderHelperProvider().builderDetails}');
                # *This keeps returning null*

                return BuilderHomepage();
              })
          // home: BuilderHomepage(),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output of the above code comes as:

```
I/flutter (31260): builder Details: null
```

My application did not quit or stop between the two operations. Under what circumstances would get reinitalised?

Comment: Your variable gets reinitialized because you use `BuilderHelperProvider().setBuilderDetails(...)` and `BuilderHelpProvider().builderDetails`.  Each time you call `BuilderHelpProvider()`, you construct a *new* `BuilderHelperProvider` object.  If you want to refer to the same object, you will need to keep a reference to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just make them static and you will be fine

```
static  var _builderDetails;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ardeshir ojan this solved my issue.